# Setting up Leapdroid through its "install" zip files

Tags: windows, installation, android, zip, emulator

A while back, I uninstalled Leapdroid from my desktop. Trying to recently reinstall it greeted me with the fact that the original downloads have been taken offline. Luckily I have an installation on one of my portable hard drives, but just copying and pasting the install directory doesn't work. Inside of the Leapdroid directory is an "install" directory that has 2 zip files (for x64 and x86) that have all Leapdroid files in them. How would I set up a fresh Leapdroid using these files?

[image]